# send var js to django view in select dynamic

Tags: select, dynamic

I am doing select dependent and I got a problem when making the query's, here the js

```
function cargar_paises() {
$.getJSON('cargar_paises', {}, function (data) {
    $('#paises').empty();
    $('#paises').append('<option value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
    $.each(data, function (id, desc) {
        var option = $('<option></option>', {value:(id+1), text:desc});
        $('#paises').append(option);
        });
    });
}
```

and my view

```
def cargar_paises(request):
if request.is_ajax:

    pais = Pais.objects.all()
    paises = []

    for s in pais:
        aux = []
        id = s.pk
        aux.append(id)
        nombre = s.nombre
        aux.append(nombre)
        paises.append(aux)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(paises), mimetype='aplication/json')
```

the problem is when I print the values ​​in the select and send the id to another query, the values ​​that I take are the index of the select and not the value of id_pais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work this out a little better using a list of dictionaries instead of a list of lists, even using the dJango `.values()`, but to keep it simple, you ca use you exact same approach,

```
function cargar_paises() {
$.getJSON('cargar_paises', {}, function (data) {
    $('#paises').empty();
    $('#paises').append('<option value="0">Seleccione ...</option>');
    $.each(data, function (item) {
        var option = $('<option></option>', {value:item.id, text:item.nombre});
        $('#paises').append(option);
        });
    });
}
```

and in the view,

```
def cargar_paises(request):
    if request.is_ajax:

        pais = Pais.objects.all()
        paises = []

        for s in pais:
            aux = {}
            aux['id'] = s.pk
            aux['nombre'] = s.nombre
            paises.append(aux)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(paises), mimetype='aplication/json')
```

Remember, you can map Python dictionaries to Json objects, and python lists to Json arrays, another good hint is to use [django-dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) it's a very good tool to do what you want, anyway is good to se this kind of things out of dJango.

**Edit**

I really thought about it, use the `.values()` in the query set, your view,

```
def cargar_paises(request):
    if request.is_ajax:
        paises = Pais.objects.values('id', 'nombre')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(paises), mimetype='aplication/json')
```

you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: considering id_pais table fields and name when generating content for me to select what is the problem persists, "cargar_paises' give me all records but selecting a value of id_pais = 1 returns me:

"GET / cargar_departamentos? pais = 0 HTTP/1.1"

when the result should be:

"GET / cargar_departamentos? pais = 1 HTTP/1.1"

then the value is taken as the index of the select and not id_pais I think or am I printing the index value of the list

Comment: But that's another question, and its solution is pretty similar, `$.getJSON('cargar_paises', {}, function (data) {})` if you see the first brackets are empty, `$.getJSON('cargar_departamentos', {id_pais: 1}, function (data) {})` where 1, is remplaced whit the id pais you're given by the user, and then access the parameter trough the request.GET parameter, pprint it and you'll see the magic, anyway, I suggest you to ask another question, because this is no that correlated with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the id's as:

```
var option = $('<option></option>', {value:(paises[0].aux.id+1), text:desc});
```